# Modelo vs. Formulario

Tags: significado-en-contexto

Quisiera preguntar si hay alguna diferencia de significado entre “formulario” y “modelo” en el contexto de “[el modelo 790 es un documento de pago de tasas](https://www.consumoteca.com/servicios-publicos/modelo-790/)”. O sea, solo quisiera saber si "formulario" y "modelo" son sinónimos. ¡Muchas gracias por antemano!

Answer (score 5):

*Formulario* es el término genérico:

> Impreso con espacios en blanco.

*Modelo* hace referencia a **uno** en particular dentro de los que integran un conjunto de formularios de una entidad.

---

La redacción real es *Formulario modelo número 790* pero se abrevia utilizando solo uno de los sustantivos, por lo que es comprensible cualquiera de las siguientes opciones siempre dentro de este ámbito:

- Formulario modelo 790
- Formulario 790
- Modelo 790